# LinkedList implementation C++ error pointer indirection

Tags: c++

I'm just starting out with C++. I was trying to write a simple LinkedList in C++. 
However I'm getting the following errors because I can't figure out why I can't call the member function `printAll` using the Link object `*newLinkThree`.

```
main.cpp:40:16: error: member reference type 'Link *' is a pointer; maybe you
      meant to use '->'?
  *newLinkThree.printAll(newLinkThree);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
               ->
main.cpp:40:3: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('void' invalid)
  *newLinkThree.printAll(newLinkThree);
```

This is my code-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Link {
  char* value;
  Link* next;
public:

  Link(char* val, Link* nextLink) {
    value = val;
    nextLink = next;
  }

  ~Link() {
    value = NULL;
    delete[] next;
  }

  void printAll(Link* top) {
    if(top->next == NULL) {
      cout<<top->value<<endl;
      return;
    }

    cout<<top->value<<endl;
    printAll(top->next);
  }
};

int main() {

  char* first = "First";
  char* second = "Second";
  char* third = "Third";

  Link* newLink = new Link(first, NULL);
  Link* newLinkTwo = new Link(second, newLink);
  Link* newLinkThree = new Link(third, newLinkTwo);
  *newLinkThree.printAll(newLinkThree);
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `operator.` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator*`. So

```
*newLinkThree.printAll(newLinkThree);
```

is equivalent to

```
*(newLinkThree.printAll(newLinkThree));
```

But you can't invoke `operator.` on a pointer.

You can add parentheses to specify the precedence:

```
(*newLinkThree).printAll(newLinkThree);
```

or just as the error message suggested,

```
newLinkThree->printAll(newLinkThree);
```

Comment: Thanks! My printAll isn't printing all the three values though. It's only printing Third for some reason. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @Kek Well, that's another question. But before asking a new one, I suggest you try to debug and find out the specific problem. If you still can't solve it then ask a new question again.

Comment: @Kek Some of the problems: `nextLink = next;` should be `next = nextLink;`, in the constructor. `delete[]` should be `delete`, in the destructor.